# How can I access ListItem in a Wicket JQuery TabbedPanel from the panel on the tab?

Tags: java, jquery, wicket

I have the following code in Wicket 7.3 with JQuery 2.1.4:

```
public class MyTabbedPanel extends JQueryGenericPanel<List<ITab>>
    implements ITabsListener {
...
  @Override
  protected void onInitialize() {
    super.onInitialize();

    this.add( new ListView<ITab>( "tabs", this.getModel() ) {
      @Override
      protected ListItem<ITab> newItem( int index, IModel<ITab> model ) {
        ListItem<ITab> item = super.newItem( index, model );
        item.setVisible( model.getObject().isVisible() );
        item.setOutputMarkupId( true );
        return item;
      }

    @Override
    protected void populateItem( ListItem<ITab> item ) {
```

How can I access this **item** from the Java code in the panel? I have added icons to each item and want to enable/ disable them when the panel changes.

I have tried in the panels code:

```
ListItem item = this.findParent( ListItem.class );
```

but this only gives item = null. There is a "LoadingPanel.class" as a parent. But this does not have a ListItem or any of the other components I have added to the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to make the icons "reactive". I.e. instead of trying to find the ListItem to modify its icon better put the logic for this to the icon itself, so every time Wicket renders an icon the icon itself calculates whether to be shown or not and what to graphics show.

Comment: Interesting approach. But I have no clue how to create a "reactive" icon in WIcket. Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Add a Java component for the icon, e.g. WebComponent and override #onComponentTag() to set the CSS class or image url, and override #onConfigure() to set the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the ListView you're showing here is just rendering the "tabs", not the panels itself.
The currently visible ITab's panel is added somewhere else in MyTabbedPanel.

You could extend ITab:

```
public interface ILoadingTab extends ITab {
  boolean isLoaded();
}
```

In `#populateItem()` add an icon to the ListItem depending on `#isLoaded()`.

You tab implementation's `#isLoaded()` then asks LoadingPanel whether it has finished loading.

Comment: You are correct. ListView only renders the tabs and I have a "GenericTab" which extends ITab und which holds the panel to be displayed. I do not get the idea, how 'isLoaded()' can help me in modifiying a link or icon on the tab title?